# Importing/automating keyframes in Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere, adobe, keyframes, automation, script

I want to get a stationary view on a moving subject, which needs to be staying within his square box on the final video (the camera should follow him).

So far I got away by clicking every 15 second to create a new keyframe and drag the canvas such that the object is centred in the final 1×1 layout.

I am going to automate this with a simple Python script.

The output of the script could be a sequence of coordinates, in whatever format Premiere wants them, so that it would replace my desperate clicking (45 hours of footage overall × 4 × 3600 = 650k clicks). Hence, does anyone know how to import / export keyframes so that I can figure how to craft such a hack?

Alternatively, but I don't fancy this, I can crop the video using ffmpeg and import that, but that wouldn't allow for later corrections.

Comment: Premiere doesn't support Python scripting.  DaVinci Resolve does.

Comment: After Effects would probably be more appropriate for [tracking a moving subject](https://youtu.be/tqWWhChc8RA), the process is almost entirely automated.

Comment: Yeah, @Ambo100, my student yesterday showed me some dark magic in AE (I've never used before). Haha, I still think programming is easier 